# Login problem after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 - suspect keyboard

Tags: upgrade, keyboard, login

I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 21.10 (Impish)
When I tried to log in via gnome, my usual username/password wasn't recognised.
I then did Ctr Alt F1 (or F3? - I can't remember) and was able to access a terminal
login screen. It seemed that some characters typed at the keyboards were not being
echoed correctly to the screen - for instance 'g' would appear as something like 'g[[' .
However, I was able to login at this screen.
Suspecting a keyboards broblem, I then did:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all

However the command said that server is already at the newest version.
I am now wondering what to do - thanks for any advice.
Ian.

Comment: Try another keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Update: This sorted the problem out:

> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Thanks for all who have looked at this!